How to print query execution plan in MongoTemplate
I am trying to write an aggregation pipeline using MongoTemplate (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb).
Since I am trying it for the first time the pipeline is very simple and hypothetical,
Criteria ct = Criteria.where("category").in(List.of("Book","Electronics"));
        ProjectionOperation pj = Aggregation.project().and("name").as("productName")
                                    .and("price").as("productPrice")
                                    .andExpression("concat($category, '-', $name)").as("fk");
        
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(ct), pj);
        AggregationResults<Product> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "items", Product.class);

My goal is to replicate the following mongo command that prints the execution stats using java code,
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    $match:
      {
        category: {
          $in: ["Book", "Electronics"],
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        productName: "$name",
        productPrice: "$price",
        fk: {
          $concat: ["$category", "-", "$name"],
        },
      },
  },
]).explain('executionStats');

How to express the same using java code?

The Aggregation class (which you are already using in your code) has withOptions method, and this allows specify your explain option.

@prasad_ thank you for your suggestion, this
Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(ct), pj).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().explain(true).build());
indeed works. Is there a way to mimic "explain('executionStats')" operation?

Here is an idea: How can I coax Spring Data to show me mongo's query plan (a.k.a cursor.explain())
